# How to call a switch class in main?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a beginner in programming, I have to make a project to university. Can you tell me, how can I call a class with a switch that I've created in main?

I have a switch in main, and after choosing one of options I want it to display next switch.

### Switch class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ComputerServiceTSz
{
    class Priceofservices
    {
        void SuperSwitch()
        {
            {
                int x = 0;

                Console.WriteLine("Please, choose type of service.");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Cleaning");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Repair");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Upgrade");

                x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (x)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {

                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        {

                        }
                        break;
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

### Main class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ComputerServiceTSz
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool done = false;
            while(!done)
            {

                {
                    int x = 0;

                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to computer repair automatic helpdesk.");
                    Console.WriteLine("1 - List of currently avaivable servisants");
                    Console.WriteLine("2 - List of services");
                    Console.WriteLine("3 - Price of services");
                    Console.WriteLine("4 - Quit");
                    Console.WriteLine("<------------------------------------------------------>");

                    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    switch (x)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                List<Servicemanlist> lista = Servicemanlist.CreateServicemanlist();
                                foreach (var item in lista)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                                }
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            {
                                List<string> lista = Serviceslist.CreateServicelist();
                                foreach (var item in lista)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                                }
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }
                            break;

                        case 3:


                        case 4:
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Bye, see you next time!");
                                done = true;
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                break;                               
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: I think you are struggeling with some real basics, like in this case object creation. You should really find some sources to learn those.
As for your problem, you can create a `Priceofservices` object in main by using `var x = new Priceofservices()` (where x is the name of your new variable, choose wisely!). You can call methods of that object with `x.DoStuff()`, but remember visibility, only methods that are public (or internal if you are in the same assembly) can be called from outside. Protected methods can be called by child classes.

Comment: Are you asking how to call `private` instance method? Define method as `public static`, then you can call it `Priceofservices.SuperSwitch()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an object of `Priceofservices` type and call its method `SuperSwitch`

```cs
Priceofservices pos = new Priceofservices();
pos.SuperSwitch();
```

or you can make `SuperSwitch` as `static` and call it without creation.

```cs
Priceofservices.SuperSwitch();
```

Also add `public` keyword to `SuperSwitch` to allow access outside the class `Priceofservices`

Comment: Thank you very much! :)